# What is a predicate in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, terminology

When I try to compile this code:

```
impl<S, V> Storage for Database<S>
where
    S: StoredElement,
    V: VisibleElement,
```

The compiler complains

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `V` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:77:9
   |
77 | impl<S, V> Storage for Database<S>
   |         ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

I assumed `V: VisibleElement` is a predicate, but apparently the compiler disagrees.

So, in Rust, what exactly is a predicate?

Comment: Please do a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`V: VisibleElement` *is* a predicate in this context. The problem is that the predicate doesn't constrain the types sufficiently for `V` to be relevant in any way.

The compiler sees `V` and also `V: VisibleElement`, and then it just throws them away because they have no impact on:

- which trait you are implementing (the `impl trait`)
- or the type for which you are implementing the trait (`self type`)
- or any of the constraints on either of those (the `predicates` or bounds).

For example, if the predicate included a relationship between `V` and `S` then that would make sense, because it would add information about which implementations are being defined here. For example, that could be something like this:

```
impl<S, V> Storage for Database<S>
where
    S: StoredElement<ChildType = V>,
    V: VisibleElement,
```

I've made up the types here, as I don't know where the actual types are from. This would be a meaningful usage of `V` because it is constraining `S` to not only `StoredElement` but to `StoredElement`s whose associated `ChildType` implements `VisibleElement`. This will only define the implementation of  `Storage` for `Database` where that condition (predicate) is met.

The compiler is complaining because you've added a parameter that has no impact whatsoever and that is most likely to be a mistake on your part.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I think the documentation should be clearer; I assumed I was constraining `V` _sufficiently_; and concluded predicates must be something else. It didn't occur to me that what I was doing wasn't very helpful to the compiler.